# How to skip a part of String using regex?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have this string

```
12345678(a part of string); 12345679(a part of string); ABCD220785; ABCD220785
```

And I want the output like this

```
12345678(a part of string); 12345679(a part of string); ABCD220785
```

I've Created below function to remove duplicates but it also removing the string

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SplitString(V IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  RETVAL VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
WITH cte (t,dt) AS
  ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS t,str AS dt
   FROM
    (SELECT regexp_substr (V, '[^; ]+',1, rownum) str
    FROM dual
      CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count (V, '[^; ]+')
    )
  )
SELECT DISTINCT listagg(dt,';') within GROUP (
ORDER BY t) AS servicename
INTO RETVAL
FROM cte
GROUP BY t;
RETURN RETVAL;
END;
```

Comment: Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '([^; ]+)(; \1( |$))', '\1')`

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing lists of things as delimited strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, '12345678(a part of string); 12345679(a part of string); ABCD220785;ABCD220785'
  3     from dual
  4     union
  5     select 2, 'ABCD220785;ABCD220785'
  6     from dual
  7    ),
  8  t_rows as
  9    (select id, trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^;]+', 1, column_value)) col, column_value rn
 10     from test,
 11          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                              connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ';') + 1
 13                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14    ),
 15  t_distinct as
 16    (select id, col, min(rn) min_rn
 17     from t_rows
 18     group by id, col
 19    )
 20  select id, listagg(col, '; ') within group (order by min_rn) result
 21  from t_distinct
 22  group by id;

        ID RESULT
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 12345678(a part of string); 12345679(a part of string); ABCD220785
         2 ABCD220785

SQL>
```

Comment: What won't work? I added a string you used in the comment. Looks OK to me.

Comment: See it a string comes like this `12345678(a part of string); 12345679(a part of string); ABCD220785;ABCD220785` it won't work here.

Comment: Bah! Matter of a simple TRIM function. Edited, have a look.

Comment: Is it working at your end? I'm facing compilation issue at `as sys.odcinumberlist))`.

Comment: Obviously, it works for me, you saw the demonstration. Which Oracle database version do you use? It would be nice if you copy/pasted your SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded. BTW, what "compilation issue" is it? ORA-xxxxx error code?

Comment: Had some packages issue. Solved it. Will try above code tomorrow.